# Writing a For Loop to Evaluate a Factorial

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to write a function that will return the factorial of any number that is given as input. Right now, my code is an absolute mess. Please help.

```
function factorialize(num) {
  for (var i=num, i>0, i--){
    var result = 1;
    result = result * i;
  }
  return result;

}

factorialize(5);
```

Comment: The problems were that the _for_ parameters had to be delimitated by semicolons ";" and not by commas, and that you were declaring _result_ inside the _for_ loop, so it was being rewritten all the time as 1, and the function always returned 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
 function factorialize(num){
     var result = 1;

  for(var i = num ; i >0 ; i--) {

     result = result * i ;

    }
   return result;

}
```

you can also use recursion for this

```
 function fact(num) {

   if(num > 1) 

         return num * fact(num-1);
else
     return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function factorialize(num) {
    var result = 1;
    while (num) {
        result *= num;
        num--;
    }
    return result;
}

factorialize(5);

// or a very short version:
function f(n) { return +!~-n || n * f(n - 1); }
```